# stringWrite - Length can't be less than zero

Tags: c#, stringwriter

I'm exporting a datagrid data to Excel and the exporting function worked fine until I fixed the header row, now an error appears in the export function in this line:

```
sAux = stringWrite.ToString().Substring(0, stringWrite.ToString().IndexOf("<tr"));
```

It seems stringWrite is empty and so a warning message appears:

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Length can't be less than zero.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Length cannot be less than zero." on a blank line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5633661/length-cannot-be-less-than-zero-on-a-blank-line)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means that `IndexOf()` returned -1. IOW, it didn't find `<tr`. You can't take a `SubString(0, -1)`.

Declare a variable, and assign the result of `IndexOf()` to that variable, and make sure the substring you want was found:

```
Idx = stringWrite.ToString().IndexOf("<tr");
if (Idx > -1)
{
   sAux = ...
}
```