# Get current root path url of the page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, iis

I have Function use to get the root folder path and i start-up code of my ASP.NET application.
but no work, it show error" Length cannot be less than zero"
below is my code, anyone can give me advises? thanks

```
        Private Function FindDir(ByVal path As String) As String

        Dim url As String = Request.ServerVariables("SCRIPT_NAME")

        Dim initialSlash As Integer = 0
        Dim CurrentSlash As Integer = 0
        Dim myRootPath As String = Nothing

        initialSlash = url.LastIndexOf("/")
       

        myRootPath = url.Substring(0, initialSlash)

        CurrentSlash = myRootPath.LastIndexOf("/")

        Do While CurrentSlash <> initialSlash And CurrentSlash <> 0
            myRootPath = myRootPath.Substring(0, CurrentSlash)
            CurrentSlash = myRootPath.LastIndexOf("/")
        Loop

        myRootPath = myRootPath.Substring(1)

        Return myRootPath

    End Function
```

Comment: Why you are doing all this when you simply can get that by `Dim url As String = Request.ApplicationPath`.

Comment: Hello @G3nt_m3caj, thank you for your comment and advise. let me learn more about Request.ApplicationPath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be that your Lastindexof() method did not find the specified value, so it returned -1. This is the cause of the error.

You can refer to this link to solve the problem: [“Length cannot be less than zero.”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5633661/length-cannot-be-less-than-zero-on-a-blank-line)

Comment: Hi Theobald Du, you are right, i find that Lastindexof() method get one "\". eg. www.stackoverflow.com\questions. so return 0